# WF6 Workflow Foundation resume without applying changes to PersistentStore

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

I need to simulate an existing WF process "on dry", meaning it was persisted to db and now I resume it to collect various "what-if" data.

After it completes, I Abort() it, but it leaves WF instance void.

```
        app = new WorkflowApplication(flowChart);
        app.Load("guid");
        app.InstanceStore = CreateInstanceStore();
        var evt = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        app.PersistableIdle = e =>
        {
            evt.Set();
            return PersistableIdleAction.None;
        };
        app.ResumeBookmark("bookmark");
        evt.WaitOne();
        app.Abort();
    private SqlWorkflowInstanceStore CreateInstanceStore()
    {
        SqlWorkflowInstanceStore instanceStore = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(connectionString)
        {
            InstanceCompletionAction = InstanceCompletionAction.DeleteNothing
        };
        var instanceHandle = instanceStore.CreateInstanceHandle();
        var view = instanceStore.Execute(instanceHandle,
            new CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        instanceHandle.Free();
        instanceStore.DefaultInstanceOwner = view.InstanceOwner;
        return instanceStore;
    }
```

I need to "undo" any changes the wf state may have done to persistent store.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `CreateInstanceStore()` ? Code listing would be great...

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev above